# Show that it's impossible find a pointwise convergence sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequence-of-function

Let $X= [0,1]^{[0,1]} = \{ f : f: [0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]\}$ be endowed with the topology $T$ of pointwise convergence.

For every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, consider the function $f_n \in X$ defined by the following formula: $f_n(t)=10^nt- \lfloor10^nt \rfloor$, for all $t\in [0,1]$.

Here $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is the floor function.

Show that int is not possible to find some indices $n(1) < n(2)< \cdots < n(k) < \cdots$ in $\mathbb{N}$ such that the sequence $(f_{n(k)})_{k=1}^{\infty}$ is pointwise convergent.

Note that we have $f_n(0)=f_n(1)=0$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

I tried to prove the by contradiction. Suppose $f_{n(k)} \rightarrow f$. Then there exists some $N>0$ so that for all $n(k)>N$, $|f_{n(k)} -f|< \epsilon$. But from here, I couldn't get any where to find a contradiction.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Especially, $f_n(0)=10^n$.

Comment: Did you mean $f_n(t)=10^{n}t -[10^{n}t]$?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo! Just edited the question.

Comment: You need to study the particular function in question. How does this function behave? If I give you some $t$ in $[0,1]$, for example, $t=\frac 13$, can you tell me what $f_1(t), f_2(t), ...$ are? (Note: that particular question has an easy answer for each $n$) What happens with other $t$? Can you exploit that behavior? Maybe for some given subsequence $f_{n(k)}$, figure out a $t$ for which $f_{n(k)}(t)$ does not converge?

Comment: If we have some $t$ that is a non-terminating, non-repeating decimal, then $f_n(t)$ will not converge. Otherwise for the other $t$'s there is always a subsequence that will converge. Is this right? So we pick some $t\in [0,1]$that is a non-terminating, non-repeating decimal. We will never find a subsequence that will convergence. Is this it for the proof?